# How Can I Harden the TCP/IP Stack in Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, tcpip, ddos

I would like to make sure that my Windows 2008 servers are hardened against DDOS attacks.

There is a Microsoft Technet article on [Hardening the TCP/IP stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302363.aspx), but it was last revised in January 2006. There is another article (somewhat duplicative) specifically for [Windows Server 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;324270#XSLTH3123121122120121120120), but I can't find one for Windows Server 2008.

Does anyone know if these protections are already in place in Windows Server 2008's TCP/IP stack or if they are still relevant?

I found a portion of a book on Safari called *Windows Server 2008 TCP/IP Protocols and Services* that [read](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780735624474/ch11lev1sec3):

> TCP in Windows Server 2008 and Windows
>   Vista use SYN attack protection to
>   prevent a SYN attack from overwhelming
>   the computer.

and

> TCP in Windows Server 2008 and Windows
>   Vista no longer supports the
>   TcpMaxConnectResponseRetransmissions,
>   SynAttackProtect, TcpMaxHalfOpen, and
>   TcpMaxHalfOpenRetried registry values.

...but I can't find a mention of the other registry values nor a second source for this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They re-wrote the TCP/IP stack in Vista/2008 and included many security related changes.

You may be interested in reading the "[Next Generation TCP/IP Stack](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/bb545475.aspx)" document from Microsoft as it contains links to the [new registry settings](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=12AC9780-17B5-480C-AEF7-5C0BDE9060B0&displaylang=en), [enhancements & security protections](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb878127.aspx) and others.

Comment: Did you see anything on security? The link you linked to mentioned performance enhancements only (as far as I saw).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the DISA / NSA Windows 2008 Server Security and Technical Implementation Guide (STIG) here (Scroll down for Windows guides): 
[DISA IASE Site](http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/checklist/)

The STIG has a number of security tweeks and registry changes designed to harden your network stack (and local machine in general).